# Create singleton instance via extension per app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

In the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/), it says that some instances need to be create once per app like HKHealthStore:

> You need only a single HealthKit store per app. These are long-lived objects. Create the store once, and keep a reference for later use.

Is doing something convenient like below safe or is there a better way?

```
public extension HKHealthStore {

    class var sharedInstance: HKHealthStore? {
        if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            return nil
        }

        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = HKHealthStore()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

}
```

That way I can do this without polluting with custom managers:
`HKHealthStore.shareInstance?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes`

Is this ok or is there a better architectural approach?

Comment: In the same docs, Apple says: `Like many classes in HealthKit, the HKHealthStore class should not be subclassed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
class MyHealthStore:HKHealthStore {
    static let sharedInstance = MyHealthStore()
}
```

Now you can use `MyHealthStore.sharedInstance` and it will always return the same store.

You can also achieve the same without any subclassing:

```
class MyCustomClass:NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = MyCustomClass()
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
}
```

And now you can use `MyCustomClass.sharedInstance.healthStore`

Comment: In the same docs, Apple says: `Like many classes in HealthKit, the HKHealthStore class should not be subclassed.`

Comment: Cool thx, what I still like using the extensions because I do not have to introduce new classes. We can just leverage what's already there.

Comment: You might be right. However, you may also consider the possibility of creating a useful singleton class instead of the dummy one as I illustrated. For example, this class can hold and be responsible for all health related tasks that you need in your app. In this case you can move all of the logic into it and have very simple code in your other classes